# Laravel hasManyThrough with ManyToMany pivot

Tags: laravel, model, relationship, eloquent

I am making a game and I have users which have facilities and for this I use ManyToMany

```
user_facilities
    -user_id
    -facility_id
```

But each relation must have a facility level, so I've added facility_levels table and each of this levels must be connected to the ManyToMany relation. So user_facilities now looks like this

```
user_facilities
        -user_id
        -facility_id
        -level_id
```

**level_id** is the connections between the facility which the user owns and which level it is.

My question is how do I connect this in the models?

The User model now has this

```
public function facilities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Facility', 'user_facilities');
}
```

And Facility

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_facilities');
}
```

So how do I get the level of the facility which the user owns?
In blade I hope there is a way I can use something like

```
{{ $user->facility->level->property }}
```

Answer (score 2):

`level` is part of the `user_facilities` table not of `facility`

Therefore, you should be able to access the `level_id` from the many to many *relationship* of **user** and **facility**

One thing you can do is to access the immediate table (also called **pivot table**).

First, edit your relationship to include the extra attributes.

```
public function facilities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Facility', 'user_facilities')
                ->withPivot('level_id');
}

public function users()
{   // if you omit this EDIT/UPDATE, you cannot do this:
    // $facility->users()->first()->pivot->level_id;
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_facilities')
                ->withPivot('level_id');
}
```

**Take note that when accessing a many to many relationship, Laravel will immediately assign a pivot attribute onto the result which contains details about the pivot table of the two models**

Now try accessing the extra column:

```
$facility = $user->facilities->first();
$level_id = $facility->pivot->level_id;
// now you can use $level_id for finding the level.
$level = Level::find($level_id);
```

Now, since you can do that, you can also create a model for the *many to many* relationship of **user** and **facility** that will have that property of `level_id`

Let's create a new model called `UserFacility` that will extend `Pivot`.

This will be your Pivot model for many to many relationship of user and facilities.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserFacility extends Pivot
{
}
```

Then update your `users` and `facilities` relationships as follows.

```
public function facilities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Facility', 'user_facilities')
                ->using('App\UserFacility');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_facilities')
                ->using('App\UserFacility');
}
```

Notice that `using` method.

```
$userfac = $users->facilities->pivot; // <-- pivot will now be an instance of App\UserFacility
echo $userfac->level_id;
```

Lastly,

If you don't want the `pivot` attribute name, you can change it using the `as` method, chain it after the `belongsToMany` method, like this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_facilities')
                ->as('UFac')
                ->using('App\UserFacility');
}


$userfac = $users->facilities->UFac; // <-- you can now access the pivot table using the property `UFac`
echo $userfac->level_id;
```

It may also be possible that your *pivot table* has a relationship with a `level` since it has a `level_id`. Don't worry, it's possible, just add this function in your `UserFacility` model.

```
public function level()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Level');
}
```

Now you can do this!

```
$user->facilities->first()->UFac->level; // <-- this will be an instance of App\Level
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many